# "The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns" Error

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I am getting "`The PivotTable field name is not valid. To create a PivotTable report, you must use data that is organized as a list with labeled columns`" error when I open my **Excel sheet**.

I ran a macro and found error pivot table. But strangely that sheet doesn't have any Pivot or its hidden. Is there a way I can find and `Delete` this Pivot ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This error message usually appears because one or more of the heading cells in the source data is blank. To create a pivot table, you need a heading for each column.

Admitting that I do not have any further background details on your situation, you could try the following:

- Unhide Excel columns, in case you have hidden cells (you mentioned to have already completed this check)
- Delete empty Excel columns or use a name as column header
- In the Create PivotTable dialog box, check the Table/Range selection to make sure you haven’t selected blank columns beside the data table.
- If there are any merged cells in the heading row, unmerge them and add a heading in each separate cell.
- Last but not least, consider [trouble shooting with a macro](https://www.contextures.com/excelpivottablelistinfo.html#head)

Comment: Thank you so much ! your macro helped me to zero down to the pivot which was giving error and I was able to solve my problem. Thanks once again

Comment: Great that it worked and good luck with your project

Answer (score 1):

Usually, the merged columns are the tricky ones. A good example of such an issue is an SQL Server Reporting Services report, where mostly the header columns are merged as well as the grouped by rows or items.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://www.pivot-table.com/2018/11/07/list-all-pivot-tables-and-their-styles/) has a macro that will list the pivot tables in a workbook. I'm not familiar with a way to find them from the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this will help in every case, but I got this error and was only able to get rid of it by recreating the pivot table (which means the source data wasn't the problem in my case).